# Bi directional self-referential table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to model a "Related products" feature. I currently have an `Alternative` model that looks something like this, which relates two products

```rb
class Alternative < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product_one, class_name: 'Product'
  belongs_to :product_two, class_name: 'Product'
end
```

What I'm trying to achieve is create an `Alternative` row **once** to have Product A an alternative to Product B, and vice versa. `Alternative.create(product_one: productA, product_two: productB)`

Ideally, this is what I'd like to end up with:

```rb
porductA.alternatives = [productB]
productB.alternatives = [productA]
```

This is what I currently have & is not working:

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_alternatives, lambda { |product|
                                    unscope(:where).where(product_one_id: product.id).or(where(product_two_id: product.id))
                                  }, class_name: 'Alternative'
  has_many :alternatives, through: :product_alternatives
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want two `belongs_to` associations to the same model then you do not only need to define the `class_name` for the association but also how the foreign_keys are named in the database table because both columns need to use different names and both names do not follow Rails default conventions.

That means you need to change your model to something like this:

```
class Alternative < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product_one, class_name: 'Product', foreign_key: 'product_one_id'
  belongs_to :product_two, class_name: 'Product', foreign_key: 'product_two_id'
end
```

And you need to make sure that those columns exist in the database table.

Read more about the [`foreign_key` option in the Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-foreign-key).